# Delete Item From Object Without Convert An Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, object

I want to delete or filter records with insertedRow = 1. But since it is not an array, filter or forEach does not work. When I wanted to convert it to array, it put them all in the 0th index. If possible, I want to do it without converting it to array. Could you help me?

**dType:**

```
 export class dType{
    
        costRef?: string;
    
        insertedRow: number;
    
    }
```

**definition and filling func of clickedRecords:**

```
clickedRecords?: dType;

async function mGrid_RowClick (): Promise<void> {

    return new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject) => {

      try {

        const selectedRows = mGrid.current!.getSelectedRows();

        state.clickedRecords= selectedRows;

        resolve();

      } catch (ex) {

        reject(ex);

      }

    });

  }
```

**dto from state:**

```
  const dto: dType = state.clickedRecords;
```

**dto:**

```
[

    {

        "costRef": "ivr_98",

    },

    {

        "insertedRow": 1

    },

    {

        "insertedRow": 1

    }

]
```

Comment: Based on your output, `state.clickedRecords` is not of type `dType` but probably `Array<dType>`. Since it's an Array you should be able to use `.filter`.

Comment: @Jacob edited for clickedRecord details.

Comment: You just need to fix your type; clearly `clickedRecords?: dType;` is a bug. Change it to `clickedRecords?: Array<dType>;` or `clickedRecords?: dType[];`

Answer (score 1):

The Question is not clear. You have mentioned that you want to delete or filter records with insertedRow = 1. Your sample data is an array of object. But you're referring this as a object.

You're assigning a `state.clickedRecords` to `dto`.

```
const dto: dType = state.clickedRecords;
```

As per your sample input `state.clickedRecords` will return array of objects. But you're assigning the array of object to object type variable `dto`. you have to correct the above line by below line.

```
const dto: Arry<dType> = state.clickedRecords;
```

Once you done this change, you'll be able to do filtering records with insertedRow = 1 like below.

```
dto.filter((record) => record.insertedRow === 1)
```